# Why is this SQL view causing SSIS to hang and lock my DB?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I've been working on an SSIS project for automating some reporting.  It's very early so there's not a lot going on yet.  I have two dim tables: Item, Customer.  They are copied from our ERP.

The Item table is set up with a Slow Changing Dimension, so it should be an exact copy of the item table from our ERP plus some historical data.

The overall workflow goes like this

1. Load dim tables with customers, items.
2. Load 3 raw data tables with outputs from three different stored procedures
3. Insert a record into a header table to log the run ID and timestamp
4. Load 3 fact tables with the modified raw data.  This uses 3 different views on the raw data tables.  SSIS data flow uses these views as a data source.

[image]

Two of these raw data views join with the dim_Items table to get some additional information that wasn't in the raw data.
Out of these, The InvWipValueDetails view is causing big problems with locking up my dim_Item table when SSIS is running and I haven't been able to figure out why.

When the Load InvNotUsed Details data flow is running, I see there is one lock on my dim_Items table and it takes about 5 - 10 seconds to run.

```
select  
    object_name(p.object_id) as TableName, 
    resource_type, resource_description, *
from
    sys.dm_tran_locks l
    join sys.partitions p on l.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id
```

[image]

When the Load InvWipValue Details data flow is running, I have 33 locks!!  It is stuck in the validation phase.  After a couple minutes it finally finishes.
[image]

I'm getting similar behavior when I'm launching visual studio or trying to modify anything, I've had to go into offline mode, otherwise I'm stuck with VS hanging for a few minutes while it tries to validate.

So what is it that I'm doing that could be causing these validation issues?  This is going to make growing the project very difficult.

Item Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dim_Item](
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UNIQ_KEY] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [PART_CLASS] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [PART_TYPE] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTNO] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [PART_NO] [char](25) NOT NULL,
    [REVISION] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [PROD_ID] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTPARTNO] [char](25) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTREV] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPT] [char](45) NOT NULL,
    [U_OF_MEAS] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [PUR_UOFM] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [ORD_POLICY] [char](12) NOT NULL,
    [PACKAGE] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [NO_PKG] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [BUYER_TYPE] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [STDCOST] [numeric](13, 5) NOT NULL,
    [MINORD] [numeric](7, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ORDMULT] [numeric](7, 0) NOT NULL,
    [USERCOST] [numeric](11, 5) NOT NULL,
    [PULL_IN] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PUSH_OUT] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [STATUS] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [PERPANEL] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ABC] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [LAYER] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [PART_SPEC] [char](100) NOT NULL,
    [PUR_LTIME] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PUR_LUNIT] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [KIT_LTIME] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [KIT_LUNIT] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [PROD_LTIME] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PROD_LUNIT] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [PART_SOURC] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [INSP_REQ] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CERT_REQ] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CERT_TYPE] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [SCRAP] [numeric](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SETUPSCRAP] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
    [BOM_STATUS] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [BOM_LASTDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [SERIALYES] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LOC_TYPE] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [DAY] [numeric](1, 0) NOT NULL,
    [DAYOFMO] [numeric](2, 0) NOT NULL,
    [DAYOFMO2] [numeric](2, 0) NOT NULL,
    [SALETYPEID] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [FEEDBACK] [text] NOT NULL,
    [ENG_NOTE] [text] NOT NULL,
    [BOMCUSTNO] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [LABORCOST] [numeric](13, 5) NOT NULL,
    [INT_UNIQ] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [EAU] [numeric](14, 0) NOT NULL,
    [REQUIRE_SN] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OHCOST] [numeric](8, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PHANT_MAKE] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CNFGCUSTNO] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [CONFGDATE] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [CONFGNOTE] [text] NOT NULL,
    [XFERDATE] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [XFERBY] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [PRODTPUNIQ] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [MAKE_BUY] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LABOR_OH] [numeric](8, 2) NOT NULL,
    [MATL_OH] [numeric](8, 2) NOT NULL,
    [MATL_COST] [numeric](13, 5) NOT NULL,
    [OVERHEAD] [numeric](13, 5) NOT NULL,
    [OTHER_COST] [numeric](13, 5) NOT NULL,
    [STDBLDQTY] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [USESETSCRP] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CONFIGCOST] [numeric](13, 5) NOT NULL,
    [OTHERCOST2] [numeric](13, 5) NOT NULL,
    [MATDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [LABDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [OHDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [OTHDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [OTH2DT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [STDDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [ARCSTAT] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [IS_NCNR] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TOOLREL] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TOOLRELDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [TOOLRELINT] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [PDMREL] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PDMRELDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [PDMRELINT] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [ITEMLOCK] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LOCKDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [LOCKINIT] [char](8) NULL,
    [LASTCHANGEDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [LASTCHANGEINIT] [char](8) NULL,
    [BOMLOCK] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [BOMLOCKINIT] [char](8) NULL,
    [BOMLOCKDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [BOMLASTINIT] [char](8) NULL,
    [ROUTREL] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ROUTRELDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [ROUTRELINT] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [TARGETPRICE] [numeric](13, 5) NOT NULL,
    [FIRSTARTICLE] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [MRC] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [TARGETPRICEDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [PPM] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [MATLTYPE] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [NEWITEMDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [BOMINACTDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [BOMINACTINIT] [char](8) NULL,
    [MTCHGDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [MTCHGINIT] [char](8) NULL,
    [BOMITEMARC] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [INVENTOR_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UNIQ_KEY] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Customer Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dim_Customer](
    [CUSTNO] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTNAME] [char](35) NOT NULL,
    [PHONE] [char](19) NOT NULL,
    [FAX] [char](19) NOT NULL,
    [BLINKADD] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [SLINKADD] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [TERRITORY] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [TERMS] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [CREDLIMIT] [numeric](9, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PROFILE] [text] NOT NULL,
    [CUSTNOTE] [text] NOT NULL,
    [ACCTSTATUS] [char](9) NOT NULL,
    [DIVISION] [char](12) NOT NULL,
    [SREPS] [char](100) NOT NULL,
    [CREDITOK] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [RESL_NO] [char](16) NOT NULL,
    [AR_CALDATE] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [AR_CALTIME] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [AR_CALBY] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [AR_CALNOTE] [text] NOT NULL,
    [AR_HIGHBAL] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [CREDITNOTE] [text] NOT NULL,
    [ACCT_DATE] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [SAVEINIT] [char](8) NULL,
    [OUT_MARGIN] [numeric](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TL_MARGIN] [numeric](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [MAT_MARGIN] [numeric](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [LAB_MARGIN] [numeric](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [MIN_ORDAMT] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SCRAP_FACT] [numeric](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [COMMITEM] [numeric](1, 0) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTSPEC] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
    [LABOR] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [MATERIAL] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SPLIT1] [numeric](1, 0) NOT NULL,
    [SPLIT2] [numeric](1, 0) NOT NULL,
    [SPLITAMT] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SPLITPERC] [numeric](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TOOLING] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SIC_CODE] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [SIC_DESC] [char](35) NOT NULL,
    [DELIVTIME] [char](7) NOT NULL,
    [STATUS] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [SERIFLAG] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OVERHEAD] [numeric](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [IS_EDITED] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [SALEDSCTID] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTPFX] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [ACTTAXABLE] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [INACTDT] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [INACTINIT] [char](8) NULL,
    [modifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsSynchronizedFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [isQBSync] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [internal] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [CUSTOMER_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CUSTNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Views on Raw Data Tables:

```
CREATE VIEW raw.vwInvNotUsedDetails
AS

SELECT 
    inu.uniq_key,
    cpn.CUSTPARTNO AS CustomerPN,
    inu.part_no,
    inu.revision,
    inu.descript,
    inu.part_class,
    inu.part_type,
    inu.partmfgr,
    inu.mfgr_pt_no,
    inu.warehouse,
    inu.stdcost,
    i.TARGETPRICE AS TargetPrice,
    inu.qty_oh,
    inu.extcost AS ExtStdCost,
    inu.qty_oh * ISNULL(i.TARGETPRICE, 0) AS ExtTargetPrice,
    inu.lastused,
    DATEDIFF(d, lastused, GETDATE()) AS LastUsedDays,
    raw.fn_CustomerInventoryAgingStatus(inu.lastused, default) AS InvType

FROM raw.InvNotUsed inu
JOIN dbo.dim_Item i ON i.UNIQ_KEY = inu.uniq_key
LEFT JOIN (
    select
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by int_uniq order by c.status, i.revision) rn,
       INT_UNIQ,
       --uniq_key,
       --i.PART_NO,
       i.CUSTPARTNO
    from dbo.dim_Item i
    join dbo.dim_Customer c on i.custno = c.CUSTNO
)cpn ON cpn.INT_UNIQ = inu.uniq_key 
    AND cpn.rn = 1 --only select the first one if there are duplicate associated customer parts.  this may make mistakes but its probably the best option for right now.


CREATE VIEW raw.vwInvWipValueDetails
AS
     SELECT iwv.uniq_key,
            iwv.PART_NO,
            cpn.CUSTPARTNO,
            iwv.REVISION,
            iwv.PART_CLASS,
            iwv.PART_TYPE,
            iwv.DESCRIPT,
            iwv.stdcost,
            i.TARGETPRICE,
            iwv.qtyoh,
            iwv.QtyInWip,
            iwv.InvtValue AS StdInvValue,
            iwv.qtyoh * ISNULL(i.TARGETPRICE, 0) AS TgtInvValue,
            iwv.WipValue AS StdWipValue,
            iwv.QtyInWip * ISNULL(i.TARGETPRICE, 0) AS TgtWipValue,
            iwv.TotalValue AS StdTotalValue,
            (iwv.qtyoh + iwv.QtyInWip) * ISNULL(i.TARGETPRICE, 0) AS TgtTotalValue
     FROM [raw].[InvWipValue] iwv
          JOIN dbo.dim_Item i ON i.UNIQ_KEY = iwv.uniq_key
          LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [i].[INT_UNIQ] ORDER BY c.status,
                                                                  i.revision) rn,
           [i].[INT_UNIQ],
           --[i].[UNIQ_KEY],
           --i.PART_NO,
           i.CUSTPARTNO

    FROM dbo.dim_Item i
         JOIN dbo.dim_Customer c ON i.custno = c.CUSTNO
) cpn ON cpn.INT_UNIQ = iwv.uniq_key
    AND cpn.rn = 1; 


CREATE VIEW raw.vwPoOpenDetails
AS 
SELECT 

    part_no,
    Revision,
    PARTMFGR,
    PONUM,
    CONUM,
    ITEMNO,
    SUPNAME,
    BalanceQty,
    COSTEACH,
    PoBalAmt
FROM raw.PoOpenDetails
```

Comment: try not loading the raw data in parallel after the `truncate`

Comment: will do thanks for the tip.

Comment: THEYRE_FINE_IF_YOU_LIKE_ORACLE `ORA-00972 Identifier is too long`

Comment: Can you clarify: even without any query even running, you have to keep waiting for validation while in SSIS design? How long do you wait for validation?

Comment: What about with (nolock) hint?

Comment: I _much_ prefer using `sp_whoisactive` to troubleshoot this kind of thing - it gives you a lot more info straight away, like who is locking, why it's locking and how long

Comment: Thanks Mitch! I agree. Not my column names, legacy database.  Didn't bother renaming them.

Comment: Nick - yes, it's hanging on validation before even running.  Validation can hang for minutes.  This view runs in ssms in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is second join where we are doing rank , get this code out in cte .

ie

```
        CREATE VIEW raw.vwInvWipValueDetails
    AS 
    with temp1 
         as
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [i].[INT_UNIQ] ORDER BY c.status,
                                                                      i.revision) rn,
               [i].[INT_UNIQ],
               i.CUSTPARTNO

        FROM dbo.dim_Item i
             JOIN dbo.dim_Customer c ON i.custno = c.CUSTNO

             )
             ,cpn as(select * from temp1 where rn = 1)

         SELECT iwv.uniq_key,
                iwv.PART_NO,
                cpn.CUSTPARTNO,
                iwv.REVISION,
                iwv.PART_CLASS,
                iwv.PART_TYPE,
                iwv.DESCRIPT,
                iwv.stdcost,
                i.TARGETPRICE,
                iwv.qtyoh,
                iwv.QtyInWip,
                iwv.InvtValue AS StdInvValue,
                iwv.qtyoh * ISNULL(i.TARGETPRICE, 0) AS TgtInvValue,
                iwv.WipValue AS StdWipValue,
                iwv.QtyInWip * ISNULL(i.TARGETPRICE, 0) AS TgtWipValue,
                iwv.TotalValue AS StdTotalValue,
                (iwv.qtyoh + iwv.QtyInWip) * ISNULL(i.TARGETPRICE, 0) AS TgtTotalValue
         FROM [raw].[InvWipValue] iwv
              JOIN dbo.dim_Item i ON i.UNIQ_KEY = iwv.uniq_key
              LEFT JOIN cpn ON cpn.INT_UNIQ = iwv.uniq_key;
```

Comment: I tried this out and it ended up having an identical execution plan and only a slight duration improvement as seen on the profiler.  (cpu/read/duration) Original(2492/20115/832) with CTE (2879/20120/704)

Comment: yo can  create persistent table and refresh  then at starting of ETL.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out a solution though I'm still not quite sure why this worked, especially given that I have two very similar views and there was only a problem with one of them.

I added an index to each one of my raw tables on the item's unique id.  That's it.  The whole package verifies and runs in a couple of seconds now.

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_InvWipValue_uniq_key] ON [raw].[InvWipValue] ([uniq_key])
```